# How to get all possible sums or possiblity of sum three numbers?

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics

Got motivation from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sic_bo) and I'm trying to do this:

```
{#1 , #2 , #3, #1 + #2 + #3}
```

Where `#1, #2, #3` are integer numbers from 1 to 6 and the list is arranged so that the sum is increasing order. So the result is something like this or any resentation showing all different possible results or possibilities of the sum is also good.

```
{1, 1, 1, 3}
{1, 1, 2, 4}
{1, 2, 1, 4}
{2, 1, 1, 4}
{1, 1, 3, 5}
{1, 2, 2, 5}
{1, 3, 1, 5}
{2, 1, 2, 5}
{3, 1, 1, 5}
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Try: `SortBy[Append[#, Total[#]] & /@ Tuples[Range[6], 3], Last]`

Answer (score 5):

I think this does it.

```
Append[#, Total@#] & /@ 
  Flatten[
    Table[
      Permutations/@IntegerPartitions[n, {3}, Range[6]],
     {n, 3, 18}],
   2]
(* {{1, 1, 1, 3}, {2, 1, 1, 4}, {1, 2, 1, 4}, {1, 1, 2, 4},
    {3, 1, 1, 5}, {1, 3, 1, 5}, {1, 1, 3, 5}, {2, 2, 1, 5},
    {2, 1, 2, 5}, {1, 2, 2, 5}, {4, 1, 1, 6}, {1, 4, 1, 6},
    {1, 1, 4, 6}, {3, 2, 1, 6}, {3, 1, 2, 6}, {2, 3, 1, 6},
    {2, 1, 3, 6}, {1, 3, 2, 6}, {1, 2, 3, 6}, {2, 2, 2, 6},
      ... } *)
```

Comment: I think it missed some cases, for example the sum to be 4 then it seems like there are 3 cases `{1, 1, 2, 4},{1, 2, 1, 4}, {2, 1, 1, 4}`.

Comment: Ah I see, so order matters. (I can see that from the OP). `IntegerPartitions` doesn't care about order, but I can quickly add in a call to `Permutations` to fix this. Hold on,

Comment: @hana, so permutations are considered different? `Append[#, Total @ #] & /@ 
 Flatten[Table[Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[n, {3}, Range[6]], {n, 3, 16}], 2]`

Comment: @J.M. yes, that seems work. I want to list all cases to calcualte possibility of each outcome or over-under. Like you have 3 dices and and you want to see all different cases.

Comment: @hana I have made the edits.

Comment: @march yeah, that looks good now.

Answer (score 5):

With a slightly different output format:

```
GroupBy[Tuples[Range[6], 3], Total]
(*    <|3 -> {{1, 1, 1}},
        4 -> {{1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1}},
        5 -> {{1, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 2}, {1, 3, 1}, {2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 1}, {3, 1, 1}},
        6 -> {{1, 1, 4}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {1, 4, 1}, {2, 1, 3}, {2, 2, 2},
              {2, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {3, 2, 1}, {4, 1, 1}},
        7 -> {{1, 1, 5}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 3}, {1, 4, 2}, {1, 5, 1}, {2, 1, 4},
              {2, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 2}, {2, 4, 1}, {3, 1, 3}, {3, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 1},
              {4, 1, 2}, {4, 2, 1}, {5, 1, 1}},
        8 -> {{1, 1, 6}, {1, 2, 5}, {1, 3, 4}, {1, 4, 3}, {1, 5, 2}, {1, 6, 1},
              {2, 1, 5}, {2, 2, 4}, {2, 3, 3}, {2, 4, 2}, {2, 5, 1}, {3, 1, 4},
              {3, 2, 3}, {3, 3, 2}, {3, 4, 1}, {4, 1, 3}, {4, 2, 2}, {4, 3, 1},
              {5, 1, 2}, {5, 2, 1}, {6, 1, 1}},
        9 -> {{1, 2, 6}, {1, 3, 5}, {1, 4, 4}, {1, 5, 3}, {1, 6, 2}, {2, 1, 6},
              {2, 2, 5}, {2, 3, 4}, {2, 4, 3}, {2, 5, 2}, {2, 6, 1}, {3, 1, 5},
              {3, 2, 4}, {3, 3, 3}, {3, 4, 2}, {3, 5, 1}, {4, 1, 4}, {4, 2, 3},
              {4, 3, 2}, {4, 4, 1}, {5, 1, 3}, {5, 2, 2}, {5, 3, 1}, {6, 1, 2},
              {6, 2, 1}},
        10 -> {{1, 3, 6}, {1, 4, 5}, {1, 5, 4}, {1, 6, 3}, {2, 2, 6}, {2, 3, 5},
               {2, 4, 4}, {2, 5, 3}, {2, 6, 2}, {3, 1, 6}, {3, 2, 5}, {3, 3, 4},
               {3, 4, 3}, {3, 5, 2}, {3, 6, 1}, {4, 1, 5}, {4, 2, 4}, {4, 3, 3},
               {4, 4, 2}, {4, 5, 1}, {5, 1, 4}, {5, 2, 3}, {5, 3, 2}, {5, 4, 1},
               {6, 1, 3}, {6, 2, 2}, {6, 3, 1}},
        11 -> {{1, 4, 6}, {1, 5, 5}, {1, 6, 4}, {2, 3, 6}, {2, 4, 5}, {2, 5, 4},
               {2, 6, 3}, {3, 2, 6}, {3, 3, 5}, {3, 4, 4}, {3, 5, 3}, {3, 6, 2},
               {4, 1, 6}, {4, 2, 5}, {4, 3, 4}, {4, 4, 3}, {4, 5, 2}, {4, 6, 1},
               {5, 1, 5}, {5, 2, 4}, {5, 3, 3}, {5, 4, 2}, {5, 5, 1}, {6, 1, 4},
               {6, 2, 3}, {6, 3, 2}, {6, 4, 1}},
        12 -> {{1, 5, 6}, {1, 6, 5}, {2, 4, 6}, {2, 5, 5}, {2, 6, 4}, {3, 3, 6},
               {3, 4, 5}, {3, 5, 4}, {3, 6, 3}, {4, 2, 6}, {4, 3, 5}, {4, 4, 4},
               {4, 5, 3}, {4, 6, 2}, {5, 1, 6}, {5, 2, 5}, {5, 3, 4}, {5, 4, 3},
               {5, 5, 2}, {5, 6, 1}, {6, 1, 5}, {6, 2, 4}, {6, 3, 3}, {6, 4, 2},
               {6, 5, 1}},
        13 -> {{1, 6, 6}, {2, 5, 6}, {2, 6, 5}, {3, 4, 6}, {3, 5, 5}, {3, 6, 4},
               {4, 3, 6}, {4, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 4}, {4, 6, 3}, {5, 2, 6}, {5, 3, 5},
               {5, 4, 4}, {5, 5, 3}, {5, 6, 2}, {6, 1, 6}, {6, 2, 5}, {6, 3, 4},
               {6, 4, 3}, {6, 5, 2}, {6, 6, 1}},
        14 -> {{2, 6, 6}, {3, 5, 6}, {3, 6, 5}, {4, 4, 6}, {4, 5, 5}, {4, 6, 4},
               {5, 3, 6}, {5, 4, 5}, {5, 5, 4}, {5, 6, 3}, {6, 2, 6}, {6, 3, 5},
               {6, 4, 4}, {6, 5, 3}, {6, 6, 2}},
        15 -> {{3, 6, 6}, {4, 5, 6}, {4, 6, 5}, {5, 4, 6}, {5, 5, 5}, {5, 6, 4},
               {6, 3, 6}, {6, 4, 5}, {6, 5, 4}, {6, 6, 3}},
        16 -> {{4, 6, 6}, {5, 5, 6}, {5, 6, 5}, {6, 4, 6}, {6, 5, 5}, {6, 6, 4}},
        17 -> {{5, 6, 6}, {6, 5, 6}, {6, 6, 5}},
        18 -> {{6, 6, 6}}|>    *)
```

Comment: ncie orgainization as well

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

nmax = 6;

result = 
  SortBy[{Sequence @@ ##, Total@##} & /@ 
  Tuples[Range[nmax], 3], Last];

Short[result, 5]
```

[image]